# Upgraded aws.java.sdk.version from 1.11.510 to 1.11.825 , now getting error - com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, maven, aws-sdk

In my Spring Boot App, I upgraded aws.java.sdk.version from 1.11.510 to 1.11.825 ,now getting error:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint -

2020-08-18 16:58:22 [main] INFO  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@247bddad: startup date [Tue Aug 18 16:58:22 CDT 2020]; root of context hierarchy
2020-08-18 16:58:23 [main] WARN  c.a.i.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher - Fail to retrieve token 
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:100)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.getToken(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:91)
```

Pom uses:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${aws.java.sdk.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.cloud.aws.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Reverting it back to version 510 works fine.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has already been discussed at [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/556).
But in my case, I changed the log level as follows. In the file ***application.yml***, I added

```
logging:
  level:
    com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils: error
    com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher: error
```